# Can I use WDS Bridging to make failover internet connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wds

Currently I have two different ISPs in my apartment.

Is it possible to connect two separate routers to them, join them with WDS bridging, and somehow make the router A use router B's WAN connection, if router A has no access to internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WDS bridging is a solution for extending a wireless network over a larger
area, improving coverage, and is perhaps not what you are asking for,

If you are looking for using two ISPs at once, so that performance
is combined and fail-safe is automatic, your best bet is a
Dual Wan router.

A
[load-balancing router](https://www.amazon.com/slp/load-balancing-router/v9pu9ck437yc8ov),
also called Dual-Wan or Multi-Wan, can connect directly to both ISPs
or to both routers.

This would have the advantage of automatically distributing all the
connections without you manually needing to specify any routes.

See one random article (more can be found):
[Best Dual Wan Routers (Load Balancing Business Firewall Routers) For Multiple Internet Connections](https://www.pickmyrouter.com/best-dual-wan-routers/).

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc!